# Radio button (column 1) not getting selected if I click on any other column in a row in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table, radio-button, servicenow

I have created a simple 3 column table with column 1 as a radio button. The problem is upon clicking any of the other two columns, I could not get a radio to be selected. The radio gets selected when we click on it specifically. [My actual code snippet in servicenow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BkJX.png)

Here's my code :

```
 <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="add in c.services track by $index">
    <td><input value="1" id="radio_1" name="type_radio" type="radio" ng-click="c.onServiceSelection(add)"/></td> 
    <td>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="clickable" ng-click="c.onServiceSelection(add)">{{add.Name}}</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="clickable" ng-click="c.onServiceSelection(add)">{{add.Profile}}</a> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Not able to get the radio button working. I have tried making use of ID and name, but it results in selecting the first radio button, no matter where you click

```
<div>
    <label for="test">Radio Button Label</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="radio" id="test" name="test" />
</div>
```

Comment: Inside ng-repeat you generate multiple radio buttons with same id and value. This should be different. Like <input value="{{$index+1}}" id="radio_{{$index}}" name="type_radio" type="radio" ng-click="c.onServiceSelection(add)"/>